# Is there a way to pass variables from different methods into a single method?

Tags: java

In the below code snippet, I have 4 methods `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` in class `test`. Each method contains a number of variables. I would like to pass some of the variables from methods `A`, `B`, and `C` into method `D`. In other words:

```
public class test {
    public void A() {
         int a;
     }

    public void B() {
         int b;
     }

    public void C() {
         int c;
     }

    public void D(a, b, c) {
         int d = a + b + c;
     }
}
```

Comment: for this you need to call d() and need to pass the variable

Comment: make a b and c class level variables... then access like this.a, this.b and so on.

Comment: I suggest you to read about variable's scope in java.

Comment: Use static variable which you want to in method D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You have declared he variables `a, b, c` inside the methods, consequently these variables are therefor method scoped. That is they can only accessed within that scope.

If you want to retain the variable state outside of the method you need to make these variables object scoped variables.

```
public class test {
    int a, b, c;
    public void A() {
         this.a=1;
     }

    public void B() {
         this.b=2;
     }

    public void C() {
         this.c=3;
     }

    public void D() {
         int d = this.a + this.b + this.c;
     }
}
```

Comment: This have one major problem compared to a local variable, `a`,`b` and `c` have a value even if you never call `A()`, `B()` and `C()`. This could lead to pretty strange behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Thihara you can also return the variable in each method and call method in `D()`

```
public class test {
public int  A() {
     int a;
     return a;
 }

public int  B() {
     int b;
     return b;
 }

public int C() {
     int c;
     return c;
 }

public void D() {
     int d = A() + B() + C();
 }
}
```